# When do casts call the constructor of the new type?

Tags: c++, casting

What are the rules to determine whether or not a particular static_cast will call a class's constructor? How about c style/functional style casts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any time a new object is created, a constructor is called.  A `static_cast` always results in a new, temporary object (but see comment by James McNellis) either
immediately, or through a call to a user defined conversion.  (But in
order to have an object of the desired type to return, the user defined
conversion operator will have to call a constructor.)

When the target is a class type, C style casts and functional style
casts with a single argument are, by definition, the same as a
`static_cast`.  If the functional style cast has zero or more than one
argument, then it will call the constructor immediately; user defined
conversion operators are not considered in this case.  (And one could
question the choice of calling this a "type conversion".)

For the record, a case where a user defined conversion operator might be
called:

```
class A
{
    int m_value;
public
    A( int initialValue ) : m_value( initialValue ) {}
};

class B
{
    int m_value;
public:
    B( int initialValue ) : m_value( initialValue ) {}
    operator A() const { return A( m_value ); }
};

void f( A const& arg );

B someB;
f( static_cast<A>( arg ) );
```

In this particular case, the cast is unnecessary, and the conversion
will be made implicitly in its absence.  But in all cases: implicit
conversion, `static_cast`, C style cast (`(A) someB`) or functional
style cast (`A( someB )`),
`B::operator A()` will be called.)

Comment: "A `static_cast` always results in a new, temporary object" is not true.  As an example, given the class hierarchy `struct B { }; struct D : B { };`, the following `static_cast` creates no new object:  `D d; B& b(static_cast<B&>(d));`.  Any `static_cast` where the target type is an object type will create a new object.

Comment: @James Yes, I should have been more precise.  I was thinking of class types (since the question involved constructors); in fact, the rule is simple (and the same for all casts): if the results are a reference, there is no new object; otherwise, there is.  (In terms of the standard, the result of a type conversion is an lvalue if and only if the conversion is to a reference type.)

Comment: Interesting to note, it doesn't create a copy in the case of c data types either https://godbolt.org/z/A0zu-o

Comment: @JamesMcNellis what do you mean by object type? If I have two derived classes having the common base such as: struct A {}; struct D1 : A {  } ; struct D2 : A { D2(const A&) } ; then D1& d1; static_cast <D2&>(d1) calls the ctor

Answer (score 14):

A constructor for a class type is called whenever a new instance of that type is created.  If a cast creates a new object of that class type then a constructor is called.  Overload resolution determines which of the constructors for a class type are called given particular arguments.

If the target type of a `static_cast` is a class type, it will create a new object of the target type.

A `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, or `reinterpret_cast` will never create a new class-type object, and thus will never call a constructor.

Since a C-style cast always performs some combination of `static_cast`, `const_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`, it will create a new object in the same circumstances that a `static_cast` would create a new object.

Comment: That's right, but it's important to say *when* it creates a new instance (IIRC function-style cast always does and static cast does when it's more than cv-qualification).

Comment: The only time a new class type object is created is via `static_cast` when the target type is a class type.  I've updated the answer with that detail.

Comment: Note that if the source type has a conversion operator to the target type, then the static cast itself might not call a constructor, but nevertheless "a constructor is called". The conversion operator might well call one, plus there's a potentially-elided copy construction of the return value to consider. That copy can only be elided in situations where the conversion operator does call some ctor, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 4):

If there's a suitable conversion constructor that conversion constructor will be called by `static_cast`:

```
class Class {
public:
    Class( int ); //<< conversion constructor
};

int what = 0;
Class object = static_cast<Class>( what );
```

the same applies to C-style casts and "functional" casts.

```
int what = 0;
Class object = (Class)what;

int what = 0;
Class object = Class( what );
```

Comment: What about if the constructor is explicit? I'd assume it would still be called.

Comment: @Mankarse: Yes, `explicit` means it can't be called without you specifying the type. When you specify the type it will be called.