# Explicit constructor and static_cast

Tags: c++, explicit, static-cast

```
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int a):m(a){}
    int padd1, m, padd2;
};

void Bar(Foo){}

int main()
{
    Bar(11); // OK, gives error
    auto x = static_cast<Foo>(37);
    x.m;
}
```

Is it ok, that `static_cast` construct `Foo` object even though its constructor is marked `explicit`?

It works in MSVC2013 and GCC http://ideone.com/dMS5kB

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do casts call the constructor of the new type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260989/when-do-casts-call-the-constructor-of-the-new-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `static_cast` will use the `explicit` constructor.

> **5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**
>
> 4 An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a
>   static_cast of the form **`static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);`
>   is well-formed**, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5). The
>   effect of such an **explicit conversion** is the same as performing the
>   declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable
>   as the result of the conversion. The expression e is used as a glvalue
>   if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

Answer (score 2):

`explicit` combined with constructor means that compiler won't perform any implicit conversion from `int` to `Foo` , asking one to `deliberately` cast it.

If your ctor wasn't explicit , even this expression `Bar('a');` would compile.