# Order of casting in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to ask about casting in C++.
I heard that when casting is ambiguous compiler should return an error,
but, just for better understanding, I tested it and it didn't, moreover, it used functions in quite weird order. When:

```
A foo;
B bar = foo;
```

it used casting operator, but when I typed:

```
bar = static_cast<B>(foo);
```

it used single argument constructor.

Can anyone explain why it acts in this way?

The whole code which I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A (const B& x);
    A& operator= (const B& x);
    operator B();
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B (const A& x) {
        cout << "constructor B" << endl;
    }
    B& operator= (const A& x) {
        cout << "Assign B" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    operator A() {
        cout << "Outer B" << endl;
        return A();
    }
};

A::A (const B& x) {
    cout << "constructor A" << endl;
}
A& A::operator= (const B& x) {
    cout << "Assign A" << endl;
    return *this;
}
A::operator B() {
    cout << "Outer A" << endl;
    return B();
}

int main ()
{
    A foo;

// First one
    B bar = foo;

    bar = foo;
    foo = bar;

// Second one    
    bar = static_cast<B>(foo);

    B bar2 = static_cast<B>(foo);
    foo = static_cast<A>(bar);
    B bar3 = foo;
    A foo2 = bar3;
    A foo3 = B();
    foo3 = B();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

My output:

```
Outer A
Assign B
Assign A
Copy constructor B
Copy constructor B
Copy constructor A
Outer A
Outer B
Outer B
Assign A
```

Comment: Just for completion sake: can you add your output also to your question?

Comment: I can't see that there should be a difference. `static_cast` performs either a conversion that is present as an implicit conversion, or the opposite.

Comment: In the question text you say that `B boo = A;` "used casting operator", but in the presented code the comment on that declaration says " // calls constructor". Which is it?

Comment: I just didn't remove this comment, this is edited code from
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: I don't see `boo = static_cast<B>(foo);` in your code.

Comment: the question is good, you should just clean it up for clarity more. Remove the misleading comments in the code and comment on the part where you  want to know why.

Comment: I thought about bar, edit.

Comment: I guess you want to know why `foo = static_cast<A>(bar);` calls `Copy constructor A` and not `Outer B`?

Comment: Maybe you should add what compiler you used? I get a different result with GCC. Seems to be unspecified.

Comment: gcc version 6.1.1

Comment: The Standard specifically shows C-style casts as an example of where the conversion function should be called. The intuition would say the same should happen for `static_cast`.

Comment: if `A` is a type then `B bar = A;` is ill-formed. Please fix the question.

Comment: yeah, just a mistake, in code is correct

Comment: BTW, [coliru output is different](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/368ec6bff8ce1f5e). Compiler bug or unspecified?

Comment: Oh, a bit wrong output.
But with this one it is even more clear.

Comment: static_cast  always creates a temporary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260989/when-do-casts-call-the-constructor-of-the-new-type

Comment: @MichałZiobro let me provide [a better source of c++ information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Comment: If you compile with MSVC, you'll get a [different result](http://rextester.com/LIR68000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your compiler does not complain about ambiguity is that your constructors and assignment operators take a `const A/B&`, but `operator A()` and `operator B()` are not declared const. For the conversion of non-const objects, the compiler therefore prefers `operator A/B()`.

I think that the rest can be explained with the rules of [`static_cast` conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), which in your code amounts to behavior as in direct initialization, and overload resolution (which is why the assignment operator is only called in the last example).

Comment: Hmm, it seems you are right. But why it doesn't work same with `operator=` which is const as well?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean; which line in your example are you referring to?

Comment: Just `bar = foo;` which uses `operator=` which takes const reference instead of `operator B()`

Comment: @MichałZiobro In the first case the compiler has to choose between a converting constructor and a conversion function. In the second case it has to choose between `operator=(const A&)` and `operator=(const B&)`, so it uses the one that does not involve a conversion.